# networking configuration with 2 routers and 2 nics with windows host and fedora oracle virtual box

Tags: networking, fedora, virtualbox

How shall i configure the following scenario:

1. I had 1 host windows machine with 2 NICS and fedora installed on oracle virtual box.
2. I had 2 routers one configured for internet and other for local network.
3. I want the host machine should access first router with internet.
4. And Oracle virtual box with fedora should access the local network / or 
   access both the networks.

How should i achieve this ?

Comment: You wanna do it by changing you router's routing table or by adding rules to your firewall? Explain a bit more, it's not crystal clear.

Comment: updated the question.

Comment: If you have nothing to do with firewall, you can just set different gateways for each OS, or if both are first connected to the first router which is connected to network, you can set a rule so it'll redirect your Fedora to the other. I hope it could be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can add additional route to local network via secondary router. To do it create new configuration file in virtual machine via command:
`echo " 192.168.33.0/24 via 192.168.11.1" › /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth0.cfg`
Where 192.168.33.0/24 is local network, eth0 is name of network interface on virtual machine and 192.168.11.1 is IP address of secondary router, which is in same network with your host machine.
This method will work only if you create bridged interface for virtual machine in oracle virtual box. In other cases, please show more details about your routers and networks.